# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' whereas cur.fetchone is not None

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code :

```
cur1.execute("SELECT * FROM consommation WHERE zone=? AND date=?",(zone,date_p))
if cur1.fetchone() is not None:
    abcisses+=(cur1.fetchone()[0][11:13]+'h',)
```

but when I run it I have an error : `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`, whereas cur1.fetchone is not empty. So I don’t understand why it doesn’t work. Is there someone who know why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fetchone` fetches the data and changes state of `cursor` object, i.e. if there was only one row to fetch, next call to `fetchone` will return `None`.

Try the next:

```
cur1.execute("SELECT * FROM consommation WHERE zone=? AND date=?", (zone, date_p))
res = cur1.fetchone()
if res:
    abcisses += (res[0][11:13] + 'h',)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still have an error : `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`. Do you know why ?

EDIT : ok, it’s my fault. Your answer is good, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @Shan-x  You probably did a type somewhere.  Could you update your question with new code/traceback?